# Trying to parse YANG files using Opendaylight but run into SchemaResolutionException

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, vaadin, opendaylight

I'm currently working on a graphic tool to process YANG files, using Vaadin as my front end (integrated into Netbeans). The tool is launched on a Glassfish 4 server. All the functionalities in the tool involving YANG are either directly or indirectly reliant on Opendaylight's Yang Tools (found at: https://github.com/opendaylight/yangtools/tree/master/yang). Currently, my project builds and deploys onto the server just fine, and only encounters an error upon trying to parse the YANG files. Specifically, this parse method is described in the following class:

```
public class YangParser implements SchemaSourceProvider<YangTextSchemaSource> {
    private HashMap<SourceIdentifier,YangTextSchemaSource> sources;
    private SharedSchemaRepository repository;
    private SchemaContext schemaContext;
    private InMemorySchemaSourceCache<ASTSchemaSource> cache;
    private List<String> warnings;

    YangParser() {
        //System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel", "debug");
        sources = new HashMap<>();
        repository = new SharedSchemaRepository("yang-context-resolver");
        repository.registerSchemaSourceListener(TextToASTTransformer.create(repository, repository));
        cache = InMemorySchemaSourceCache.createSoftCache(repository, ASTSchemaSource.class);
        warnings = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    // Will be used in retriever view in order to redirect SchemaContexts into relevant locations and then parse them (as YANG files)
    public SharedSchemaRepository getRepo () {
        return repository;
    }

    public Collection<YangTextSchemaSource> getSources() {
        return sources.values();
    }

    public void registerSource(String identifier, String version, URL url)
            throws SchemaSourceException, IOException, YangSyntaxErrorException {
        registerSource(identifier, version, Resources.asByteSource(url));
    }

    public void registerSource(String identifier, String version, byte[] bytes)
            throws SchemaSourceException, IOException, YangSyntaxErrorException {
        registerSource(identifier, version, YangTextSchemaSource.wrap(bytes));
    }

    public void registerSource(String identifier, String version, ByteSource byteSource)
            throws SchemaSourceException, IOException, YangSyntaxErrorException {
        YangTextSchemaSource source = YangTextSchemaSource.delegateForByteSource(
                RevisionSourceIdentifier.create(identifier, Revision.of(version)), byteSource);
        ASTSchemaSource ast = TextToASTTransformer.transformText(source);
        SourceIdentifier actualIdentifier = ast.getIdentifier();

        // Fixup YANG source identifier if the provided YANG model has a different actual identifier
        if (!source.getIdentifier().equals(actualIdentifier))
            source = YangTextSchemaSource.delegateForByteSource(actualIdentifier, byteSource);

        cache.schemaSourceEncountered(ast);

        sources.put(source.getIdentifier(), source);


        repository.registerSchemaSource(this, PotentialSchemaSource.create(
                source.getIdentifier(), YangTextSchemaSource.class, PotentialSchemaSource.Costs.IMMEDIATE.getValue()));
    }

    public void parse() {
        SchemaContextFactory factory = repository.createSchemaContextFactory(SchemaSourceFilter.ALWAYS_ACCEPT);
        Collection<SourceIdentifier> requiredSources = new HashSet<>(sources.keySet());
        // Parse all available YANG models, if we fail remove failed model and retry with remaining models
        while (!requiredSources.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                schemaContext = factory.createSchemaContext(requiredSources).checkedGet();
                break;
            } catch (SchemaResolutionException e) {
                if (!e.getUnsatisfiedImports().isEmpty()) {
                    for (SourceIdentifier id : e.getUnsatisfiedImports().keySet()) {
                        String imports = e.getUnsatisfiedImports().get(id).stream()
                                .map(ModuleImport::getModuleName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
                        warnings.add(String.format("%s tries to imports missing model: %s",
                                id.toYangFilename(), imports));
                        System.err.printf("%TF %TT: %s\n", System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                warnings.get(warnings.size() - 1));
                    }
                }

                if (e.getFailedSource() != null) {
                    requiredSources.remove(e.getFailedSource());
                    warnings.add(String.format("%s failed to parse as a valid YANG model",
                            e.getFailedSource().toYangFilename()));
                    System.err.printf("%TF %TT: %s\n", System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            warnings.get(warnings.size() - 1));
                } else {
                    requiredSources = new HashSet<>(e.getResolvedSources());
                }

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Returns whether sending the files to the URL was successful or not
    public boolean sendSchemaContextToPlace(String place){
        //Shouldn't need to check is schemaContext is null because that happens beforehand inside RetrieverView
        //String charset = "UTF-8";
        //String CRLF = "\r\n";
        String trimmedPlace = place.trim();
        //String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //ArrayList<File> listOfFilesToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
        int responseCode = -1;

        try {
            Set<Module> schemaModules = schemaContext.getModules();
            URL url = new URL(trimmedPlace);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //The following two commented out sections may be unnecessary since the files are directly
            //created remotely with respect to their appropriate URLs; the connection is still necessary
            //to see if the responsecode is ok
            /*
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pwOutput = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
            */

            for (Module m: schemaModules) {

                File temp = new File((new URL(trimmedPlace + (trimmedPlace.substring(trimmedPlace.length() - 1).equals("/") || trimmedPlace.substring(trimmedPlace.length() - 1).equals("\\")
                        ? "" : "/") + m.getName())).toURI());
                PrintWriter pwTemp = new PrintWriter(temp);
                pwTemp.write(m.getSource());
                pwTemp.close();
                /*
                pwOutput.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                pwOutput.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textFile\"; filename=\"" + temp.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
                pwOutput.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                pwOutput.append(CRLF).flush();

                Files.copy(temp, output);
                output.flush();
                pwOutput.append(CRLF).flush();

                pwOutput.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
                pwOutput.close();*/
            }

            responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();


        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.printf("The URL you provided, %s, is in an incorrect format.", place);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.print(e.getCause());
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.print("URL conversion to URI failed.");
        }
        return responseCode == 200;
    }

    public SchemaContext getSchemaContext() {
        return schemaContext;
    }

    public Collection<String> getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public void addWarning(String warning) {
        warnings.add(warning);
    }

    @Override
    public CheckedFuture<? extends YangTextSchemaSource, SchemaSourceException> getSource(SourceIdentifier sourceIdentifier) {
        YangTextSchemaSource source = sources.get(sourceIdentifier);
        return source != null ? Futures.immediateCheckedFuture(source) : Futures.immediateFailedCheckedFuture(
                new MissingSchemaSourceException("URL for " + sourceIdentifier + " not registered", sourceIdentifier));
    }
}
```

In the error log (attached at the very bottom), the offending line is:

```
schemaContext = factory.createSchemaContext(requiredSources).checkedGet();
```

The issue here is with the checkedGet method (i.e. I believe createSchemaContext is successful), unless I interpreted it wrong; the specific line is near the top of the error log:

```
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCheckedFuture.checkedGet(AbstractCheckedFuture.java:85)
```

Specifically, in the error log, it seems that I ran into a ExecutionException while attempting to execute the checkedGet method; looking into the relevant class shows that checkedGet looks like:

```
try {
     return get(timeout, unit);
}
.... <2 other exception catches> ....
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw mapException(e)
}
```

My main issue here is that I can't seem to interpret the error log in a meaningful way; the only thing that really makes sense to me is the last "Severe" error; this exception is one I throw manually inside RetrieverView (another one of my classes; not included, but essentially the flow is as follows: I create a new YangParser(); then that parser calls registerSource(___) many times, which simply registers YANG files pulled from a remote repository - NONE of the registerSource calls encounter any exceptions as far as I know; finally, the parser calls parse (on all the registered sources), and then runs into the error shown in the log).

So, what about the two other errors? The first Severe one at the top makes no sense to me: what does it mean "SchemaResolutionException{unsatisfiedImports={}}"? That seems like there would be NO unsatisfied imports, since the array is empty. The cause for this error is just as confounding to me: what is this "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: GET_IDENTIFIER"? It's certainly not in the offending class, SharedSchemaContextFactory:

https://github.com/opendaylight/yangtools/blob/master/yang/yang-parser-impl/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/yangtools/yang/parser/repo/SharedSchemaContextFactory.java

Can someone provide some help?

Error Log:

```
Severe:   SchemaResolutionException{unsatisfiedImports={}}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.ReflectiveExceptionMapper.newWithCause(ReflectiveExceptionMapper.java:31)
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.ExceptionMapper.apply(ExceptionMapper.java:80)
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.ExceptionMapper.apply(ExceptionMapper.java:31)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$MappingCheckedFuture.mapException(Futures.java:1809)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCheckedFuture.checkedGet(AbstractCheckedFuture.java:85)
        at ANXExplorerV2.YangParser.parse(YangParser.java:107)
        at ANXExplorerV2.RetrieverView.lambda$new$c6839ed1$1(RetrieverView.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:360)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:477)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:242)
        at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:75)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:220)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:444)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:625)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:471)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:414)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.lambda$new$1(PushHandler.java:146)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.callWithUi(PushHandler.java:236)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.onMessage(PushHandler.java:522)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onMessage(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:87)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onRequest(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:77)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:224)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:114)
        at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:67)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2290)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:594)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$3.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:345)
        at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:340)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:448)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$3.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:272)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$3.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusSession.notifyMessageHandlers(TyrusSession.java:576)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onMessage(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:871)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onMessage(TyrusWebSocket.java:212)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.TextFrame.respond(TextFrame.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:807)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:562)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.onDataAvailable(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.onDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:453)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandler(InputBuffer.java:1089)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandlerOnProperThread(InputBuffer.java:1080)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.append(InputBuffer.java:963)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: GET_IDENTIFIER
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.repo.SharedSchemaContextFactory$2.apply(SharedSchemaContextFactory.java:66)
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.repo.SharedSchemaContextFactory$2.apply(SharedSchemaContextFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:906)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.add(ExecutionList.java:101)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:170)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.transform(Futures.java:567)
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.repo.SharedSchemaContextFactory.createSchemaContext(SharedSchemaContextFactory.java:127)
        ... 65 more
Severe:   java.lang.Exception: Failed to analyze schemas! Please verify that the YANG models of your agent are valid!
        at ANXExplorerV2.RetrieverView.lambda$new$c6839ed1$1(RetrieverView.java:244)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:360)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:477)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:242)
        at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:75)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:220)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:444)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:625)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:471)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:414)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.lambda$new$1(PushHandler.java:146)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.callWithUi(PushHandler.java:236)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.onMessage(PushHandler.java:522)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onMessage(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:87)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onRequest(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:77)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:224)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:114)
        at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:67)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2290)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:594)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$3.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:345)
        at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:340)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:448)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$3.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:272)
        at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$3.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusSession.notifyMessageHandlers(TyrusSession.java:576)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onMessage(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:871)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onMessage(TyrusWebSocket.java:212)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.TextFrame.respond(TextFrame.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.process(ProtocolHandler.java:807)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:562)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.onDataAvailable(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.onDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:453)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandler(InputBuffer.java:1089)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandlerOnProperThread(InputBuffer.java:1080)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.append(InputBuffer.java:963)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The SharedSchemaContextFactory source you linked to is the master version which does not match whatever version you're using (line 66 from the trace is a comment).

Comment: Hm, do you know where I can check the version on the git repo (git.opendaylight.org:29418/yangtools); I can only seem to find versions and model versions (such as in the outermost pom.xml), but none of these seem to correspond to any of the numbers here: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/downloads.html. (Scroll to the bottom, go to archived releases, and there releases have numbers next to them)

Comment: Oops, git repo should be: https://github.com/opendaylight/yangtools, my bad